# how to open Transport Security on IOS?

Tags: ios, meteor, axios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

i'm using **NativeScript-Vue** and **Axios** for calling method from my backend **(Meteor JS)** i have a problem IOS Emulator that i can't access local ip or hosting ip address, i try to find a solution and some people ask me to add some line of code on **info.plist** but it still doesn't work, on Android is working fine i just need to add some line of code on  **AndroidManifest.xml**, anyone face this problem, thank you for advance.
this is code that i add on info.plist

```
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Comment: It should be like `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>`. Did you try a clean build?

Comment: @Manoj can you show me a complete file how it look like when you add it on info.plist ? yes, i try to clean build , but no luck .

Comment: [This is an example](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/ecd9fc3e9d50f9826c0d92cef971a6663f8b2a7a/e2e/cuteness.io/app/App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist) how the file would look like

Comment: You could also allow only specific non-secure servers via the above key `NSAppTransportSecurity` - see the following link for a real-life example on how to enable only a specific HTTP server https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist#L46-L72

Comment: @Manoj i try what you said , but it doesn't work , i think my IOS Emulator can't connect to localhost machine, for what i know Android Emulator when we want to connect to localhost we use http://10.0.2.2:your port , how about IOS ?

Comment: If you use IP, you should be able to connect. Make sure the IP / URL is accessible form Simulator by hitting it on the browser.

Comment: @NickIliev it still doesn't work :( i think my IOS Emulator can't connect to localhost ip machine

Comment: @Manoj i can access ip localhost on IOS Emulator by browser image : https://imgur.com/rEIEGWA , can u show me the way you use axios ?

Comment: There is nothing you have to do specifically here, axios works the way you used to write it on Web. Only that the IP has to be whitelisted. Try to hit the API from Playground see if it works, arbitrary loads are enabled there so that would help you understand whether the issue is server Or iOS client.

Comment: solved , thank you so much :D